# How to avoid stretching of image in django sorl thumbnails

Tags: css, django, django-templates, sorl-thumbnail

I am using sorl thumbnails in my application. Now I have fixed the width as in the code:

```
{% thumbnail user.image "300" crop="centre" upscale=False as im %}
```

Now problem is, if the width of the user image is less than 300 then it stretches the image and the quality of image gets reduced.

What I want is that if width of user image is less than 300px then image should come in the centre and should not get stretched.

Please suggest. Thanks.

Edit:

I am using upscale = False
 What i am getting is:

[image]

What i want is:

[image]

Comment: fix your css. Do not hardcode height

Comment: could you please explain in details

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `crop="centre"`. This worked for me.